# Load data from odoo in html with ajax

Tags: ajax, odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-9, odoo-10

I'm in odoo create eg.

```
import xmlrpclib

username = 'admin' 
pwd = 'admin'
dbname = 'odoo9'

sock_common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/common')
uid = sock_common.login(dbname, username, pwd)


sock = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/object')

contact_ids = sock.execute(dbname, uid, pwd, 'res.partner', 'search', [])
for contact_id in contact_ids:
    contact = sock.execute(dbname, uid, pwd, 'res.partner', 'read', contact_id, [])
    print('Name is: ' + contact['name'])
```

after call xml_rpc.py file in terminal get:

Name is: Admin

Name is: Marc

Name is: Ronald

Now I want all names (Admin, Marc, Ronald) load in my html div with ajax.

```
$.ajax({
      ???
      ???
    });
```

How with ajax load data?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
url:"http://localhost:8069/connect_with_odoo",
        type:"POST",
        data:{},
})
```

put your data into the data:`{<here>}`